# Generate multiple random numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to write a script for roulette system and I want the script to run until the **bank** variable reaches 0 or 11,000, and produce three pieces of data after each spin.

I have left parts of the code out for simplicity. The code in the if else statement is not the problem. Running the script until the variable reaches a certain point is where I'm stuck.

Would anyone be able to help me rewrite this script please? Thanks in advance.

```
(function() {
  var bank = 10000;
  var bet = 1;

  function spin() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36);

    if ( number == 0 ) {
      document.write("<p>The number " + number + " is neither high nor low.</p>");
      // removed
    } 
    else if ( number > 18 ) {
      document.write("<p>The number " + number + " is a high number.</p>");
      // removed
    }
    else {
      document.write("<p>The number " + number + " is a low number.</p>");
      // removed
    }
  };

  spin();

  document.write("<p>Total bank is now " + bank + ".</p>");
  document.write("<p>The next bet is " + bet + ".</p>");

})();
```

Comment: It's not very clear what your question is, but it looks like you need a while loop somewhere, unless you have omitted it from the example.  for example, `while(bank > 0 && bank < 11000) { spin() }`

Comment: One issue I see here is Math.floor(Math.random() * 36), it should be Math.round(Math.random() * 36) since in case of Math.floor, the number 36 will only come when Math.random() = 1 hence the probability is not evenly distributed. And how do you calculate the bank and the bet amount ?

Comment: Brain, I did omit it as I didn’t really know where to start. Parthik, I will look into that now as I’m not sure what the difference is. As for your second question, I can’t discuss that just yet. I work in a casino as a guy has been coming in the last few months and playing this system and he hasn’t lost once. He’s taken us for a small fortune. I want to know if he is just lucky (which I expect), or onto something serious.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling this loop within a page (i.e. you don't want the page to hang up for the duration, or want to display results) you should use [requestAnimationFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/):

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

Then set up your loop to only call itself if the bank is within your accepted range:

```
function spinLoop() {
    spin();

    //perform your UI updates here

    if (bank >= 0 && bank <= 11000) requestAnimFrame(spinLoop);
}
```

You will, of course, need to call this function initially to start the loop:

```
spinLoop();
```